# Setup Codeigniter For Windows Azure

Tags: php, codeigniter, azure

I've been trying to Setup Codeigniter 3 on the Windows Azure platform,everything seems fine for the normal setup but when i uploaded my application(Which i did via github so all the  files are intact) and my session is set to autoload from config,i get the error "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.",Please are there settings needed to be made to run codeigniter on azure,please kindly help me with them because my entire startup depends on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have downloaded the Codeigniter3.0 from the official site: http://www.codeigniter.com/download, and set session to autoload then publish it to Azure web app, everything goes well, there is no special configurations in my testing, from the error message, it seems the resource is missing, I would suggest you use Kudu to double check the resouce: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benjaminperkins/archive/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx

Comment: Thanks alot!!!, your confirmation that it works with session autoloaded gave me push that it had to be something on my code,so it turns out that it was the .htacess/mod rewrite , it worked with the index.php in the url so i refined my google searches and i've fixed the issue,THANKS ALOT!!!!!!!